# How do i display previous and next using Unslide JQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I am using the following plugin:

http://unslider.com/

Here's the code on their page that they say I can use to display prev and next:

```
<!-- The HTML -->
<a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev">Previous slide</a>
<a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">Next slide</a>

<!-- And the JavaScript -->
<script>
    var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

    $('.unslider-arrow').click(function() {
        var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];

        //  Either do unslider.data('unslider').next() or .prev() depending on the className
        unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
    });
</script>
```

This is what my  looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/unslider-master/site/pages.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://site.com/unslider-master/src/unslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider();
});
    </script>
    <script>
    var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

    $('.unslider-arrow').click(function() {
        var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];

        //  Either do unslider.data('unslider').next() or .prev() depending on the className
        unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
    });
</script>
<script>
    var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

    $('.unslider-arrow').click(function() {
        var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];

        //  Either do unslider.data('unslider').next() or .prev() depending on the className
        unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
    });
</script>
```

This what i am including for JQuery:

code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

I put it on my site but when I click on next slide or previous slide it doesn't work.  I get no errors.  It's just clickable but nothing else.  Am I missing something? I am putting this script in the head. I am new to JS so a bit confused.  Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: not enough information. more code please or create sample on jsfiddle. you are not missing jQuery library by any chance right?

Comment: I am using this: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

Comment: please post the head tag of your page.

Comment: did you check is un-slider library is being loaded properly? and no need to use multiple script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my unslider.com example html file:

```
               <!-- The HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Unslider.com example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- JavaScript -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$('.banner').unslider({
    speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
    delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
    complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
    keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
    dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
    fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs

});
var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

  $('.prev').click(function() {
      unslider.data('unslider').prev();
  });

  $('.next').click(function() {
      unslider.data('unslider').next();
  });
  return false;
});
</script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.banner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
top: 50px;
/*z-index: -1;*/

font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
text-align: center;

color: #FFFFFF;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

background: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
.banner ul {
list-style: none;
width: 300%;
}
.banner ul li {
display: block;
float: left;

min-height: 500px;

-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
-ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;

box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.banner .inner {
padding: 360px 0 110px;

float: left;
vertical-align:-100px;
}

.banner h1, .banner h2 {

font-size: 40px;
line-height: 52px;
color: #fff;
}

.banner .btn {
display: inline-block;
margin: 25px 0 0;
padding: 9px 22px 7px;
clear: both;

color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
border : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) solid 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.banner .btn:hover {
background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
.banner .btn:active {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-o-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}

.banner .btn, .banner .dot {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
}

.banner .dots {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;
}
.banner .dots li {
display: inline-block;

width: 10px;
height: 10px;
line-height: 10px;
margin: 0 4px;

text-indent: -999em;


border: 2px solid #fff;
border-radius: 6px;

cursor: pointer;
opacity: .4;

-webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
-moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}
.banner .dots li.active {
background: #fff;
opacity: 1;
}




.unslider-arrow {
  font-family: Expressway;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  padding: 0 20px 5px 20px;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  right: 0  
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  right: 90 /* change to left:0; if u wanna have arrow on left side */ 
}
</style>
     </head>
    <!-- Body of HTML document -->

    <body>
        <div class="slider">
        <div class="banner">
          <ul>
          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
            <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
             <p>smaller p text</p>

                <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
            <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
             <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
              </div>
              </li>

           <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
             <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
             <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
              </div>
          </li>

          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
          <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
             <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>


        </div>
          <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev">&larr;</a>
          <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">&rarr;</a>
        </div>
   </body>  

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of *just* posting code as your answer, you should try to summarize **how** the code responds to OP's problem. You'll get more upvotes that way.

Comment: hi , i just paste working code to eleminate any potential problems with this free javascript website effect... but no problem i will think about ur suggestion..